# Prove $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is constant function.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let  $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ s.t $f(a)=0$. If $f$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$ and there exist $C  \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t $|f'(x)|  \leq C|f(x)|$ for all x $ \in [a,b]$, then $f(x)=0$ for all $x  \in [a,b]$

My attempt:

|$f'(a)| \leq C|f(a)|=0\Rightarrow f'(a) = 0$

Let $\epsilon=\frac{1}{C}$, then there exist $\delta > 0$  s.t for all $x \in (a,b)$ if $x\in (a,a+\delta)$, then $\frac{|f(x)|}{x-a}<\frac{1}{C}$ thus
$$|f'(x)|\leq C|f(x)|<|x-a|<\delta$$

I do not know what to do from here.

**Edit**:
I could try to think about $f'(b)$: If $f'(b)>0$ or $f'(b)<0$, then find some contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Note that 
$$ |f(x)|=|f(x)-f(a)|=\bigg|\int_a^xf'(t)dt\bigg|\le\int_a^x|f'(t)|dt\le C\int_a^x|f(t)|dt. $$
Let $F(x)=\int_a^x|f(t)dt$ and then $F(x)\ge 0, F(a)=0$. Then one has
$$ F'(x)\le CF(x)$$
and hence
$$ (e^{-Cx}F(x))'\le 0.$$
So
$$ e^{-Cx}F(x)-e^{-Ca}F(a)=\int_a^x(e^{-Ct}F(t))'dt\le0$$
or
$$ e^{-Cx}F(x)\le 0$$
or
$$ F(x)\le0$$
So $F(x)\equiv0$ or $f(x)=0$ in $[a,b]$.

Comment: very nice.${}{}$

Comment: The derivative of a function is not necessarily integrable, so this approach fails from the start.

Comment: @mathguy But in the context of this problem, the derivative is bounded by $C \max_{x\in[a,b]} f(x)$.

Comment: @XanderHenderson - even then, the derivative may not be Riemann integrable (and I don't think the question is at Lebesgue integration level - it only requires the mean value theorem for solution).